# How to handle different view/size configurations (viewWillAppear) with UITabBarController (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I have 2 viewControllers, each with its own set of constraints for when the device is rotated:

VC1: [image] [image] and VC2: [image] [image]

I set the constraints of each in their own viewController, used viewWillTransition to handle the screen rotations, and all worked perfectly. Each viewController has the following (the only difference being what is inside the [ ... ]):

```
func SetConstraints() {
    narrowConstraints = [ ... ]
    wideConstraints = [ ... ]
    activateConstraints()
}

func activateConstraints() {
    // Wide:
    if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(narrowConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(wideConstraints)
    }
    // Narrow:
    else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wideConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(narrowConstraints)
    }
}

// when view changes size - going between wide and narrow modes:
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        
        self.activateConstraints()

    }, completion: {
        _ in
        // do something after the transition
    })
}
```

Then I put both viewControllers in a tabBarController.

Now, regardless of which Item is selected, viewWillTransition of **both** viewControllers is called.  (Is this because the tabBarController is the container whose size changes?)

Now, if VC1 is rotated from narrow to wide to narrow before selecting VC2, VC2 first appears like this:

[image] Subsequent screen rotations bring it back to working as desired.

How do I apply different sets of constraints for screen rotations when using a UITabBarController?

EDIT:  ---------------------------------------

@DonMag - here is an example per our discussion below.  (I think I put enough in here to

Not to take advantage of you since you have been a tremendous amount of help to me many times - MUCH appreciated! - but I added an unanswered question:  This does not actually change the colors of the added view. I switched `self` to `superview!` in the classes but obviously that paints the entire superview rather than just the added view.

import UIKit

```
class VC1: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var storyboardView: UIView!
    
    var viewingVC1: Bool = false
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        storyboardView.backgroundColor = .black
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        viewingVC1 = true
        createNewVC1View()
    }
        
    
    
    func createNewVC1View() {
        var v = UIView()            
        v = View1class()
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        v.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 50, width: storyboardView.frame.width - 40, height: storyboardView.frame.height - 100)
        storyboardView.addSubview(v)            
    }
    
    func setConstraints()  { }

    func activateConstraintsFor(_ size: CGSize) { }

    
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        // when view changes size - going between wide and narrow modes
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
            self.activateConstraintsFor(size)
        }, completion: {
            _ in
            // if you want to do something after the transition
            if self.viewingVC1 {
                self.createNewVC1View()
            }
        })
    }
    
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        viewingVC1 = false
    }
    
}

class View1class: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // this is where a graph will be created 
        super.draw(rect)
        debugPrint("class g1")
        self.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is evaluating the **view's** `.frame` --- when the size transitions, such as on device rotation, you're looking at the wrong size.

Try changing your `activateConstraints()` func to:

```
func activateConstraintsFor(_ size: CGSize) {
    // Wide:
    if size.width > size.height {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(narrowConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(wideConstraints)
    }
    // Narrow:
    else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wideConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(narrowConstraints)
    }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
// when view changes size - going between wide and narrow modes:
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
    coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
        
        self.activateConstraintsFor(size)
        
    }, completion: {
        _ in
        // do something after the transition
    })
}
```

You *may* also want to call this in either `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` or `viewDidAppear()`:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    activateConstraintsFor(view.frame.size)
}
```

or:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    activateConstraintsFor(view.frame.size)
}
```

---

**Edit** - complete example matching your images...

**VC1**

```
class FirstViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let blueView = UIView()
    let redView = UIView()
    let greenView = UIView()

    var wideConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    var narrowConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [blueView, redView, greenView].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
        
        blueView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        redView.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        greenView.backgroundColor = .systemGreen

        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

        // narrow layout
        narrowConstraints = [

            // blue / red / green all have Leading and Trailing to view (safe-area)
            blueView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            blueView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            redView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            redView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            greenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // blue Top to view Top
            blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // red Top to blue Bottom, red Bottom to green Top
            redView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // green Bottom to view Bottom
            greenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // red Height equal to blue Height
            redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.heightAnchor),
            
            // green Height equal to 25% of view Height
            greenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.heightAnchor, multiplier: 0.25),
            
        ]
        
        // wide layout
        wideConstraints = [
            
            // blue Top and Leading to view
            blueView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // red Leading and Bottom to view
            redView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            redView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // red Top to blue Bottom
            redView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // green Top / Trailing / Bottom to view
            greenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            greenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            greenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // blue and red Trailing to green Leading
            blueView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            redView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: greenView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // red Height equal to blue Height
            redView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.heightAnchor),
            
            // green Width equal to blue Width
            greenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.widthAnchor),
            
        ]
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        activateConstraintsFor(view.frame.size)
    }
    
    func activateConstraintsFor(_ size: CGSize) {
        // Wide:
        if size.width > size.height {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(narrowConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(wideConstraints)
        }
        // Narrow:
        else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wideConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(narrowConstraints)
        }
    }
    
    // when view changes size - going between wide and narrow modes:
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
            
            self.activateConstraintsFor(size)
            
        }, completion: {
            _ in
            // do something after the transition
        })
    }
    
}
```

**VC2**

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let blueView = UIView()
    let greenView = UIView()
    
    var wideConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    var narrowConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint] = []
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [blueView, greenView].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
        
        blueView.backgroundColor = .systemBlue
        greenView.backgroundColor = .systemGreen
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // narrow layout
        narrowConstraints = [

            // blue Top / Leading / Trailing to view (safe-area)
            blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            blueView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            blueView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // green Leading / Trailing / Bottom to view
            greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            greenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            greenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // green Top equal to blue Bottom
            greenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // green Height equal to blue Height
            greenView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.heightAnchor),

        ]
        
        // wide layout
        wideConstraints = [

            // blue Top / Leading / Bottom to view
            blueView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            blueView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            blueView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // green Top / Trailing / Bottom to view
            greenView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            greenView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            greenView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // green Leading equal to blue Trailing
            greenView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            // green Width equal to blue Width
            greenView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blueView.widthAnchor),

        ]
        
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        activateConstraintsFor(view.frame.size)
    }
    
    func activateConstraints() {
        // Wide:
        if view.frame.width > view.frame.height {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(narrowConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(wideConstraints)
        }
        // Narrow:
        else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wideConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(narrowConstraints)
        }
    }
    
    func activateConstraintsFor(_ size: CGSize) {
        // Wide:
        if size.width > size.height {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(narrowConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(wideConstraints)
        }
        // Narrow:
        else {
            NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate(wideConstraints)
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate(narrowConstraints)
        }
    }
    
    // when view changes size - going between wide and narrow modes:
    override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
        super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
        coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
            
            self.activateConstraintsFor(size)
            
        }, completion: {
            _ in
            // do something after the transition
        })
    }
    
}
```

Results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I did have to use `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: This opened up another can of worms.  Subviews now don't size properly when the screen is rotated.

Comment: @Greg - you'll need to be a little more specific... I edited my answer with a complete example.

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to be cryptic.  Thank you for doing this.  I solved the problem by adding the call to create the subviews (`createNewView()`) in the completion part of `viewWillTransition`.  This in turn created another:  I have three viewControllers, each with their own 'viewWillTransition' - which I thought would belong only to their respective viewController - and each with their own version of createNewView.

Comment: Only VC1 needs the `createNewView`.  However, if I am on VC2 and rotate the screen, it crashes because the new view does not exist.  I don't know if this was the right way to fix this, but I added `var viewingVC1: Bool = false` that I set to true in `viewWillAppear` then back to false in `viewWillDisappear`, and in completion of `viewWillTransition` added: `if self.viewingVC1 { self.createNewView()  }`.

Comment: @Greg - creating and adding subviews in `viewWillTransition` sounds like a ***very bad idea***... Can you provide a complete (simple) example of what you're doing - and what's not working right when using constraint arrays as shown?

Comment: Yes, should I append to the original?  Or add a new question?

Comment: @Greg - Edit this question, since we already have the bulk of the discussion here.

Comment: Done. Ultimately, I am trying to create a graph (defined inside a class) in the view created in IB (`storyboardView`).  I had hoped to assign the class programmatically  directly to `storyboardView` in the same way I assign it to the new UIView subview, but that question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65623672/programmatically-assigning-class-to-a-uiview-created-in-storyboard-swift?noredirect=1#comment116025447_65623672) was ignored, so I did it by adding the subview.

Comment: @Greg - yeah, your other question is a bit confusing -- as well as the code you added to this question -- because of a few misconceptions. I'll give you an answer a bit later.

Comment: @Greg - I added an answer to your other question, which will hopefully clarify a few things. A side note: throw away everything you're doing in the code you added to this question. It's just not correct. And, another side note: if you override `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` in a subclass, it is up to *you* to draw the view content. Setting `.backgroundColor` there will have no effect.