# Programmatically assigning class to a UIView created in Storyboard (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

**Question:  How do I programmatically assign a class to a UIView created in Storyboard?**

I have a UIView created in IB (`graphView`) in which I would like to display one of several graphs, their definitions created in their respective classes.

To do this, I created another view programmatically then assigned the class of the selected graph to that view, then added it to the original view:

```
@IBOutlet weak var graphView: UIView!

func displayGraph(choice: Int) {
    var selectedGraphView = UIView()        
    switch choice {
        case 1: selectedGraphView = class1()
        case 2: selectedGraphView = class2()
        case 3: selectedGraphView = class3()
        default: selectedGraphView = class1()
    }
    selectedGraphView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: graphView, height: graphView)
    graphView.addSubview(selectedGraphView)
}
```

Things seem to work, but do I really need that second UIView (`selectedGraphView`)?

I tried changing it to:

```
func displayGraph2(choice: Int) {
    switch choice {
        case 1: graphView = class1()
        case 2: graphView = class2()
        case 3: graphView = class3()
        default: graphView = class1()
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to get the contents of the class to run.

Can I do it this way?  If so, what is missing?

EDIT:  Actually, there are 3 UIViews: the one in IB, the one to hold the graph, and the class itself creates one.

If, say `class1` has nothing but `print("entered class1")`, in the first case (`displayGraph`), I see "entered class1" printed.  In the second (`displayGraph2`), I get nothing.

EDIT2:
I can assign any of the classes to `graphView` in IB and get the print message from the class.  How do I assign a class to `graphView` programmatically (since what I attempted in `displayGraph2` doesn't work)?

Comment: You can just declare the variable, but not create a throwaway view: `var selectedGraphView: UIView`. Not sure if this is what you meant.

Comment: I don't know why you do it this way. Can you give more information about what are you going to do?

Comment: @Sweeper: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I just want to put something in the UIView created in IB.  That something will be defined by the selected class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add a `UIView` in Storyboard, you can assign its Custom Class. However, at run-time, you cannot *change* its class this way:

```
@IBOutlet var graphViewHolder: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // cannot do this
    let v = View2Class()
    graphViewHolder = v

}
```

One common approach, as you've done, is to add a `UIView` in your Storyboard as a "holder" (or "container") view. Then, in code, instantiate an instance of your desired Custom Class and add it as a subview to the "holder" view.

However, if you do this:

```
selectedGraphView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: graphView, height: graphView)
graphView.addSubview(selectedGraphView)
```

The newly added subview will have the size of the "holder" view, and you'll run into layout issues if / when the holder view changes size (such as on device rotation).

So, you can do it like this:

```
// let's name it "graphViewHolder" so we know we're using it as a "holder" view
@IBOutlet var graphViewHolder: UIView!

var currentChoice: Int = 1

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    displayGraph(choice: 1)
}

func displayGraph(choice: Int) {
    var selectedGraphView: UIView?
    switch choice {
    case 1: selectedGraphView = View1Class()
    case 2: selectedGraphView = View2Class()
    case 3: selectedGraphView = View3Class()
    default: selectedGraphView = View1Class()
    }
    // unwrap optional
    guard let sgv = selectedGraphView else { return }
    // does the "holder" view already have any subviews?
    //  if so, remove them
    graphViewHolder.subviews.forEach { v in
        v.removeFromSuperview()
    }
    // add the new view as a subview of the "holder" view
    graphViewHolder.addSubview(sgv)
    // we need to give the new view auto-layout properties
    sgv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        // constrain it to all 4 sides of the "holder" view
        sgv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: graphViewHolder.topAnchor),
        sgv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: graphViewHolder.leadingAnchor),
        sgv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: graphViewHolder.trailingAnchor),
        sgv.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: graphViewHolder.bottomAnchor),
    ])
}
```

Now the subview will follow the "holder" view's constraints.

Note that if you want to do something to the loaded view, you'll have to make sure it's the right class.

So, for example, if we want to call a custom func in `View2Class`:

```
    // make sure the "holder" view has a subview
    guard let v = graphViewHolder.subviews.first else {
        print("Graph View Holder has no subviews!")
        return
    }
    // make sure the subview is a View2Class instance
    guard let v2 = v as? View2Class else {
        print("The Holder subview is not View2Class!")
        return
    }
    // call a func in View2Class
    v2.myFunc()
```

Comment: To the first part:  If I understand correctly, even if I don't assign a custom class in Storyboard I can not do so at run-time - but the "holder" concept makes sense and is straightforward.  I understand how the constraints work, now applied to the subview - perfect!  Thank you again!

Comment: My only remaining questions have to do with the class itself.  If the only function inside is ````draw(_ rect: CGRect)```` whose code is simply ````debugPrint("class View1Class");  self.backgroundColor = .red````, why does the print message appear but the subview not get painted red?  And how would I go about calling it as in your example above (````v2.MyFunc````).  (I understand I would not call it, only tell when it needs to be called, but am confused about that.)

Comment: @Greg - *"why does the print message appear but the subview not get painted red?"* ...  See my answer to your other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645944/how-to-address-the-current-view-vs-superview-confusion-swift

Comment: I just saw it a few minutes ago!  And successfully tested it.  Thank you again!