# How to Address the Current View vs Superview confusion (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

Using `superview` in the class paints the entire screen but I only want to paint the smaller subview (whose dimensions are defined by `v.frame`).

How do I have the class operate only on the "current view"?

```
@IBOutlet var storyboardView: UIView!

func selectView() {
    var v = UIView()
    switch viewchoice {
        case false:
            v = View1class()
        case true:
            v = View2class()
    }
    v.frame = CGRect(x: 20, y: 50, width: storyboardView.frame.width - 40, height: storyboardView.frame.height - 100)
    storyboardView.addSubview(v)
}

class View1class: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        superview!.backgroundColor = .red
    }
}


class View2class: UIView {
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)
        superview!.backgroundColor = .blue
    }
}
```

I tried using `self` instead of `superview` but that doesn't work.

EDIT: If I wanted to paint the entire screen, could I skip creating the subview and assign the class to `storyboardView`?

Comment: Use self instead of super view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you override `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` in a subclass, it is up to you to draw the view content. Setting .backgroundColor there will have no effect.

This is a common structure for a `UIView` subclass:

```
class View1Class: UIView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        self.backgroundColor = .red
        // do any other view setup here, such as
        //  adding subviews, adding sublayers, etc
    }
    
}
```

---

**Edit**

Here is an example of two custom views - the first one uses shape layers, the second one overrides `draw()`:

**MyFirstView class**

```
class MyFirstView: UIView {
    
    let boxLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let circleLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    let lineLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        self.backgroundColor = .systemYellow

        layer.addSublayer(boxLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(circleLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(lineLayer)
        
        boxLayer.fillColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        circleLayer.fillColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        lineLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        // centered rectangle, half height and width
        let halfWidth: CGFloat = bounds.width * 0.5
        let halfHeight: CGFloat = bounds.height * 0.5
        let boxRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: halfWidth * 0.5, y: halfHeight * 0.5, width: halfWidth, height: halfHeight)
        let boxPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: boxRect)
        boxLayer.path = boxPath.cgPath
        
        // circle centered in box, 3/4ths of the shorter of width or height
        let wh: CGFloat = min(boxRect.width, boxRect.height) * 0.75
        let circleRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: boxRect.midX - wh * 0.5, y: boxRect.midY - wh * 0.5, width: wh, height: wh)
        let circlePath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: circleRect)
        circleLayer.path = circlePath.cgPath
        
        // diagonal line from top-left to bottom-right
        let linePath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: .zero)
        linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.maxX, y: bounds.maxY))
        lineLayer.path = linePath.cgPath
        
    }
    
}
```

**MySecondView class**

```
class MySecondView: UIView {
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    func commonInit() -> Void {
        self.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        
        // centered rectangle, half height and width
        let halfWidth: CGFloat = rect.width * 0.5
        let halfHeight: CGFloat = rect.height * 0.5
        let boxRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: halfWidth * 0.5, y: halfHeight * 0.5, width: halfWidth, height: halfHeight)
        let boxPath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(rect: boxRect)
        
        UIColor.red.setFill()
        boxPath.fill()
        
        // circle centered in box, 3/4ths of the shorter of width or height
        let wh: CGFloat = min(boxRect.width, boxRect.height) * 0.75
        let circleRect: CGRect = CGRect(x: boxRect.midX - wh * 0.5, y: boxRect.midY - wh * 0.5, width: wh, height: wh)
        let circlePath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: circleRect)
        
        UIColor.blue.setFill()
        circlePath.fill()
        
        // diagonal line from top-left to bottom-right
        let linePath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath()
        linePath.move(to: .zero)
        linePath.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        
        UIColor.green.setStroke()
        linePath.stroke()
        
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
}
```

**Example view controller**

```
class CustomViewsViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let firstView = MyFirstView()
    let secondView = MySecondView()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        [firstView, secondView].forEach {
            $0.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview($0)
        }
        
        // respect safe area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // firstView Top / Leading / Trailing to view (safe-area)
            firstView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            firstView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 40.0),
            firstView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),

            // firstView Height
            firstView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0),
            
            // secondView Leading / Trailing to view (safe-area)
            secondView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 60.0),
            secondView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -60.0),

            // secondView Top 20-pts from firstView Bottom
            secondView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: firstView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),

            // secondView Bottom to View Bottom (safe-area)
            secondView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: -20.0),

        ])
        
    }
    
}
```

Output - first view has `.systemYellow` background, second view has `.systemTeal` background:

[image]

and rotated:

[image]

Comment: How would I get the width of this view from inside this class?  (I tried `self.frame.width` and `self.bounds` but they return 0s.)

Comment: @Greg -  your view doesn't ***have*** a width (size), until you give it one... either by explicitly setting it or when auto-layout does its thing. Since the code you had started with was simply trying to set the background color in `draw()` (which, as you've learned, is incorrect), it's tough to offer any other help. Maybe if you describe what you're really trying to do?

Comment: Thanks again.  Just trying to figure out a couple of basic things - for example, drawing a diagonal line across the view, or a filled box that is half the width and height and centered in the view.  I had gotten rid of `draw(_ rect: CGRect)` but have adde it back.

Comment: But doesn't it have a size if it was added as a subview and the NSConstraints anchors tied all its edges to its "holder view"?

Comment: @Greg - it is ***extremely  difficult*** to discuss "in the abstract." Do you really want to ***DRAW*** a rectangle in the view? Or do you want to use a `CAShapeLayer`? Or do you want a rectangular ***subview***? I edited my answer to give you an example... one that uses shape layers and one that overrides `draw()`.

Comment: I want to do EXACTLY what you did - display some boxes, lines, circles. (And some labels.)  It looks like they both accomplish the same thing in the end - is there an advantage to using one of these over the other?

Comment: @Greg - yes, there are differences. For example: if you run that sample in a simulator,  select `Debug -> Slow Animations`, and then rotate the device, you'll see a difference in the size-change animation. Each approach has its pros and cons. Again, though, without knowing what your ultimate goal is, it's impossible to say which approach would be better. If you want to *"and some labels"* you can do so with CoreText or CATextLayers, or, more likely, you'll want to add `UILabel` subviews.

Comment: I'm just creating a simple line graph with x- and y-axis labels. I used `UILabel` subviews for the labels.  There is no need for any high performance as a game might require (which, as I read about these, sounds like `draw()` would be the choice).  `draw` also seems a little simpler.

Comment: I've played around with both and discovered that, if these views are within "holder" views (as we discussed somewhere), that the `CAShapeLayer` method seems to call the functions 2 or sometimes 3 times.  Ultimately, I went with `draw` but am now struggling with the `UILabel`s - which works well using `CAShapeLayer`.  Can you steer me in the right direction?

Comment: In general, for a custom view, you either A) add subviews and/or layers, or B) override draw. You rarely, if ever, want to do both in the same view. If you're overriding `draw` and you want to add "labels" look at the documentation for `NSAttributedString.draw(at point: CGPoint)` and `NSAttributedString.draw(in rect: CGRect)`

Comment: Thank you so much.  I can not express how much I appreciate all the help you have given me over the last months and how much more I've learned than my initial questions.   Thank you AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

Use self instead of superView.

```
self.backgroundColor = .red
```

Comment: I tried that - didn't work.  In fact, that is where I started.

Comment: I think your  view is not resizing. Add this before the frame is set. v. translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true